# regex in google sheets, match previous period or semi-colon

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want the return to be the sentence with the double question mark.

I'm using the formula `=trim(regexextract(H4,"[\.;](.*?)\?\?"))`

ex 1:

```
blah blah. 1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog?? blah blah
```

I get the right return. `1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

but ex 2:

```
blah blah. 1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. blah blah ; 2 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog?? blah blah, blah blah?
```

I get

```
1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. blah blah ; 2 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I only want

```
2 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

the sentence with the double question mark.

not sure how to make it to lookback from the question mark to the first period or semi-colon since RE2 doesn't support lookback.

Here is a sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mPFiWZ4WCOSPoae-ga3TaJOFlIfPIp7ALf-4ht6xpFo/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75027188/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of say 10 rows of _realistic-looking_ sample data along with your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: @doubleunary very helpful. I posted the sheet. 10 is an overkill. Take a look at the 3 I posted. I think it's pretty clear now.

Comment: bro, realistic-looking sample data is sensitive. others will have interest, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start at the last digit and stop at the first non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace character, use `.*(\d[\w\s]+)`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract(B5:B, ".*(\d[\w\s]+)") ) )
```

This formula exactly matches the desired results you present in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mPFiWZ4WCOSPoae-ga3TaJOFlIfPIp7ALf-4ht6xpFo/edit#gid=2100307022).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i just update the question

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
[.;]\s+(.*?)[^\w\s]
```

**Explanation**

- `[.;]` Match either `.` or `;`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any char as few as possible
- `[^\w\s]` Match a single char other than a word char or whitespace char

See the capture group matches at the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHgIzX/1).

Example code:

```
=trim(regexextract(H4,"[.;]\s+(.*?)[^\w\s]"))
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i just update the question

Comment: @jason Does it not yield the right result?